# Raw data from fitness wristband

Tags: data-manipulation, raw-data

Is there any fitness wristband that allows an easy access to the **raw data** gathered during one or more sessions, in any form available, for exporting and manipulating on the PC?

Comment: Good response, Giox79. Any additional findings really helpful and welcomed.

Comment: Put on hold after one year? It is quite surprising to me. And I'm asking about actual facts, the existance of any device of such a kind. I'm not asking about opinions or recomendations on what's the best one. I'm asking if it merely exists. And where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only a device with this features.
It's Angel, a device that has been funded using indiegogo.
At present time they accept only pre-order

http://www.angelsensor.com/

may be you can have some further info from them

Comment: Thank you! It's a very good finding. The problem is they appear to be offline,  at least the Store website. Anyway, I'll keep an eye on them. They look quite promising.

Comment: Please note that angel has been overfunded, so I think that at present time they are really busy respecting the timeline and the many order they received from Indiegogo

Comment: this device is a scam, read the commentaries in indiegogo. They took the money and the device will not be released.